# Find and move only the email addresses from one column to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a client list that contains name, address, city, state, zip code, but some randomly have an email address instead of a street address.

I need to move the email address out of the address column into a separate column on the same worksheet but still associated with the same client record.

The only constant is the "@" in the email addresses. Is there a way to do this without going through each individual client record and moving them one by one?

EDIT:

Here is a sample of the data:

[image: Screenshot showing sample data]

How do I identify only the email addresses and move them to column I?

Comment: you need to share some good sample data for us to help with this, and what the output will look like

Comment: Good point. Here is a sample of the data.

Comment: Good point. Here is a sample of the data. Column A: Customer Name, Column B: Phone Number, Column C:# of Invoices, Column D: Invoice Total, Column E: Hours, Column F: is Address Line 1, Column G: Address Line 2, Column H: Address Line 3. EX: COLUMN F -- F2:123 Main Street, F3:johndoe@email.com, F4: blank. Each ROW is a different customer. How do I identify only the email addresses and move them to column H? Sorry, I don't know how to put a sample data sheet in here.

Comment: @KariCarpenter,, Y you are looking to move `Mail Ids` to `Col H` since the `Column H is already occupied by Address line 3`,, ?

Comment: The simplest way to show sample data is to take a screenshot, upload it to imgur.com and paste the link in your question. Typically, other users will then  edit your question and inline the image. Once you reach 10 reputation, you will be able to directly paste the screenshot into your question. Note that any extra info you add must be placed in the question itself by [editing](//superuser.com/posts/1383009/edit) it, and not posted in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite straightforward to do.

**Step 1**

Turn on AutoFiltering using one of these methods:

- `Data` → `Sort & Filter` → `Filter`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>A</kbd>; <kbd>T</kbd>)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

[image: Worksheet screenshot showing AutoFilter turned on]

**Step 2**

Filter the `Address Line 1` column with a `contains` `@` custom text filter created via the down control arrow:

[image: Worksheet screenshot showing custom filter being set up]

**Step 3**

Select the filtered cells of the `Address Line 1` column that contain email addresses (the simplest way is to select the topmost cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>), extend the selection to encompass the other address columns and the email column ( <kbd>Shift</kbd>+(<kbd>Right</kbd>;<kbd>Right</kbd>; <kbd>Right</kbd>) ), and then fill right using one of the following methods:

- `Home` → `Editing` → `Fill` → `Right`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>H</kbd>; <kbd>F</kbd>; <kbd>I</kbd>; <kbd>R</kbd>)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image: Worksheet screenshot showing email addresses filled to the right]

**Step 4**

Reduce the selection by one column (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>), and then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to clear all the address columns:

[image: Worksheet screenshot showing cleared address columns]

**Step 5**

Finally, turn off AutoFiltering in the same way you turned it on, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>A</kbd>; <kbd>T</kbd>):

[image: Worksheet screenshot showing final result]

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I'm understanding your question correctly. Is all that information currently stored in just 1 column? A bit like this?
[image: Example 1]

If so, you can use **Data > Text to Columns** to split them out into separate columns. In my example, I'm using 'comma' as the 'delimiter'[(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75g2O.png) but it would work with spaces and so on depending on your data.

Here's what the output might look like after completing the wizard.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGbQp.png)

Answer (score 0):

*If you are using Excel version 2016 or higher, then you may use this Formula:*

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("@", A2:A6)), "", A2:A6))
```

*You may use this Array Formula if using lower version than 2016:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A6, 1, MIN(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("@", A2:A6)), "", MATCH(ROW(A2:A6),ROW(A2:A6))))),"")}
```

**Note:**

- Finish this Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.